# mysql cluster .net connector

Tags: mysql, .net, database-connection, cluster-computing, failover

I'm trying mysql cluster to use in a project for our customer.

The configuration I setted up is the following: 
Hardware S.O. equipment

```
Server1 - S.O. Windows 2008 R2 64bit 
Server2 - S.O. Windows 2008 R2 64bit 
Client1 - S.O. Windows 7 64bit 
Client2 - S.O. Windows 7 64bit 

UserClient2 - S.O. Windows 7 64bit 
UserClient3 - S.O. Windows 7 64bit 
UserClient4 - S.O. Windows 7 64bit 
UserClient5 - S.O. Windows 7 64bit 
UserClientXX - S.O. Windows 7 64bit (where XX is less than 15)
```

My Sql Cluster Configuration 
    Server1 - act as cluster data node 1 
    Server2 - act as cluster data node 2 
    Server1 - act as mysql node 1 (from now MYSQL-D1) 
    Server2 - act as mysql node 2 (from now MYSQL-D2)

```
Client1 - act as mysql cluster management node 1 
Client2 - act as mysql cluster management node 2
```

Client application configuration 
The following clients (from now CLIENTAPP): 
Client1, Client2, UserClient2, .., UserClientXX 
have a Microsoft .Net application that interact with mysql cluster database.

After a while the My sql cluster configuration appears to work correctly and any of CLIENTAPP it's able to connect to MYSQL-D1 or MYSQL-D2 (this is possibile by changing the connection string of .NET client application and pointing to IP of MYSQL-D1 or to the IP of MYSQL-D2).

In a perfect world CLIENTAPP automatically it's able to connect to the right server (MYSQL-D1 or MYSQL-D2), pratically:
    - if MYSQL-D1 it's down CLIENTAPP connect to MYSQL-D2 
    - if MYSQL-D2 it's down CLIENTAPP connect to MYSQL-D1

How .NET client application can interact with mysql cluster?

The best solutions I have found for my scenario are the followings: 
    1. use mysql proxy but this is in a alpha stage and I can't use it in production enviroment
    2. install cluster data node on each CLIENTAPP 
    3. use a connection string that support multiple servers (I don't know if it's supported by mysql .NET connector)
    4. rewrite my application to interact with both MYSQL-DX node (what I want to avoid)

Is there a right solutions? Which one is the best one?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on the MySQL Cluster forum:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?25,583508,584009